# Throw error in API (resouce) in identotyserver 4

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4

in `IDentityServer4` when client try to use resource (in here api) when api can't authenticate user, identityserver redirect user to IDentityServer for login.
is there any way instead of redirect user to IDentityServer throw an error like token is not valid or something

thakns

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make a change in user authentication flow, you can implement ICustomAuthorizeRequestValidator interface and register it in startup.cs.

you can check throw an exception in this class.